# How do we get improved (+1, etc) Armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, crafting, armor

I've seen there exists some kind of improved armor (for example see [Leather Armor +3](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Leather%20Armor%20+3)). But I am unable to find anything about this in the DM guide or PH. Is that official or common homebrew stuff?

And: If I'm having for example a leather armor, how would I go with improving its quality to +1, +2 or +3?

I'd think it could work to search for an NPC who can craft this and let him do the 'upgrade'. But at which costs? It could also be possible to have them as magical items (thus the increase in AC) and to loot them or have an arcane crafter enchant a normal armor.

Comment: I downvoted this question, because it shows little research effort - one of the fundamental downvote reasons. The terms "armor", "crafting", and "creating" are all listed in the index of the DMG. That same index is where I put together the page references in my answer.

Comment: I am down voting for lack of research.

Comment: Yeah, seems like I deserved that :/
But on the other hand there is now a search result for 'improve armor'.

Comment: @Akerus Well played for taking constructive criticism with good grace and good humor. :)

Comment: I am upvoting because although T.J.L.'s response is accurate, a lot of new players don't understand that the pluses on armor are a magical trait, and the accepted answer below addresses that concern. This is still a useful answer because of that.

Comment: Agreed with Aviose. Many digital rpg (Skyrim for one) has physical improvements on armors. The question is legitimate, especially if the person expects that improving armor could be found in another rulebook they don't own

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Armor +3](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/armor-3) *is* magic armor. It's listed in the DMG on page 152 as a generic item. Basic +X armor doesn't have any special effects beyond improving the wearer's armor class, so it's all lumped into a single entry.

The rules for DMs who wish to allow characters to [craft a magic item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/between-adventures#CraftingaMagicItem) are on p128-129 in the DMG.

The rules for DMs [creating a magic item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#CreatingaMagicItem) are on p214-216 (sentient items) and p284-285 (magic items in general).

Answer (score 5):

The leather armor +3 that you linked is from the entry in the DMG called "armor, +1, +2, +3" in the list of magic items. For more information about magic items, please read DMG chapter 7, section "Magic Items" and chapter 6, section "Downtime Activities." Xanathar's Guide to Everything contains additional advice and optional rules about crafting magic items.